# How to get all legal entities projects data with system admin access through D365 REST API

Tags: odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

**Dynamics365 F&O :** When trying to pull project entity data from D365 Rest API [Projects Data API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjadV.png) returning only the data which is associated with user legal entity instead of returning all projects of legal entities data.

**Note : Logged in as Sys admin.**

If we change the user legal entity, then it's returning changed entity projects data.

**Note : Getting data from OData feed source.**

Is there anyway to get all the projects data from all legal entities through API?

Comment: Take a look at [Open Data Protocol (OData) - Cross-company behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata#cross-company-behavior)

Comment: as @FH-Inway said all you need is to add ?cross-company=true to your URL